# contentSizeForViewInPopover different height in IOS4 and IOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, uipopover, contentsize

[image]

[image]

Hello,
I have UITableView with static content embedded in UIScrollView
so I have just set size in popover:

```
- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover
{    
    return CGSizeMake(600, 670);
}
```

but, I got different popover heights (see attachments). In IOS4.3 height is bigger than in IOS5. 
I don't want to check IOS version and increase/decrease height.

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, when using the navigation controller as popover contents, you have to

1. set the `contentSizeForViewInPopover` on the root controller (or anyone that is being shown as the first). (Don't try to set size on the navigation controller).
2. whenever you push/pop controllers and you want the popover size changed for the new controller on the stack, call `setPopoverContentSize:animated:` explicitly. A `UINavigationControllerDelegate` is good for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically calculate the height of your popover based on the height of your tableview and overriding `contentSizeForViewInPopoverView` like this:

```
- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopoverView {
    CGFloat width = 200.0; // Currently no way to obtain the width dynamically, only height.
    CGRect rect = [self.tableView rectForSection:[self.tableView numberOfSections] - 1];
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetMaxY(rect);
    return (CGSize){width, height};
}
```

This assumes you have 1 section. If you have more, you just need to use `rectForSection` to determine the height of each section and add them up.

Comment: `[UITable contentSize]` does exactly the same

Comment: @Sulthan That only works if you are manually calling `setPopoverContentSize:animated`. If you don't want to manually set the popover size though -- i.e. only use `initWithContentViewController` -- you can't do that because in that case, `contentSizeForViewInPopover` is called _before_ `viewWillAppear`. So the contentSize of the tableView hasn't been set yet and will always be 0.